# Remove - and + from string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset which contains 100,000+ phone numbers 90,000 are good but there are some which have - in between or  + in them I want to remove these characters and get a raw 10 digit numbers
I have numbers like

```
12345-67890 
123-456-7890
+123-456-7890
+123-456-7890
```

I want to get data like

```
1234567890
```

i.e. remove all the additional characters except the raw 10 digit number.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to update the table, the following update statements can be run:

Query 1:

```
update table1.phonenumber
set date_col = replace(phonenumber, '-', '')
where phonenumber like '%-%'
```

Query 2:

```
update table1. phonenumber
set date_col = replace(phonenumber, '+', '')
where phonenumber like '%+%'
```

Comment: The asterisk does not do what you think it does when used with `LIKE`

Comment: Thank you for providing update query it should be '%+%' and '%-%' in where clause.

Comment: @Smor - I was thinking about that as I wrote it out, thanks for clarifying. The query is updated.

Answer (score 2):

```
select replace(replace(phonenumber, '-',''),'+','')
from tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a function to strip all non-numeric.

```
/* Usage */    
SELECT dbo.usf_numbers_only('+123-456-7890');

/* Function Code */
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.usf_numbers_only
(
    @String VARCHAR(2000)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS

BEGIN
    DECLARE @Count INT;
    DECLARE @IntNumbers VARCHAR(1000);

    SET @Count = 0;
    SET @IntNumbers = '';

    WHILE @Count <= LEN(@String)
    BEGIN
        IF SUBSTRING(@String, @Count, 1) >= '0'
           AND  SUBSTRING(@String, @Count, 1) <= '9'
        BEGIN
            SET @IntNumbers = @IntNumbers + SUBSTRING(@String, @Count, 1);
        END;

        SET @Count = @Count + 1;
    END;

    RETURN @IntNumbers;
END;
GO
```